# I always get this window and I can't do anything

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

I got an Android phone, And when I turn on the phone, I always see this window.
[image]

I would like to use it, but I don’t know, how I can fix it.
Somebody could send some link about the probleme and how can I fixed it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This picture is showing the custom recovery that is installed on your device. Looks like someone installed it and used custom ROM on this phone before. By default, the phone should boot straight into the system, but in this case it seems that something's different.

One way of fixing your phone is by reinstalling the software you got on your phone (since it seems that there's something faulty with it). Go on [CyanogenMod website](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) (CyanogenMod is a custom ROM that you can install on your phone), find the page for your device, and follow the instructions that are presented. You'll have to download the ROM and Gapps package, transfer them to your phone, and install them (it's fairly easy, you'll see). After following the instructions, your phone will be ready to use.

Comment: Ok, I will check this website, I will do what I can.
Thanks your help.